# How do I write to the screen outside normal window boundaries?

Tags: software-recommendation, window-manager, notify-osd

How can I create irregularly shaped windows and/or write graphics to the screen outside window constraints?

What libraries might help me do this?  I would prefer solutions to be as portable as possible.

Answer (score 2):

### Gromit

Gromit allows you to make annotations to your screen:
[Homepage](http://www.home.unix-ag.org/simon/gromit/)

Install with `sudo apt-get install gromit`

Comment: I have also found Gromit-MPX which uses the XCOMPOSITE extension if found. Otherwise use XSHAPE.